# Will saveEventually() work if Parse server itself is down?

Tags: java, parse-server, back4app, parse-android-sdk

So this is my knowledge of how client-server interaction works.

1. Client --> Parse Server ---> MongoBD (The request went through and got saved)
2. MongoDb ---> Parse Server ---> Client. (Callback to client).

So as far as I know saveEventually has no problem if the client is offline. It will try again until the connection is back.

But what if the Server itself is down ? What will happen then ? Will the request be dropped ?
It's really important for my application as some object creations are done through saveEventually and immediately pinned to the local DB. So if this is the case the User will think his object is saved as SaveEventually is not waiting for a callback and telling the user it's done where as in reality the object was not even created in the Database. (Using Android SDK).

Comment: saveEventually should work in the same way no matter if it is the client or the server that is offline

Comment: How long with saveEventually keep on trying ? Is there like a time out for it before the request is discarded ?

Comment: I believe it will try until it reaches the server and get a success or a error. In the case of an error, it will retry a total of 5 times by default.